# i am getting errorin runnging my partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have just started MVC 4 in c#, i am having issue in rendering partial view.
i have created model for the partial view and controller action in which i am just 
sending a single string for the testing reasons but when i try to render it.
it just show the following error.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   here is my controller class.

```
enter code here

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using my_photos.Models;


namespace my_photos.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {


     public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Massage = "Hello Word";
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About() {
            ViewBag.Message = "About Page";
            return View();
        }
       public ActionResult  _RightView() {
           var model = new my_photos.Models.partial(){
               Winner = "Shafee Jan"
           };
           //ViewData["name"] = model;
           return View(model);
        }
    }
```

here is model class for partial view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace my_photos.Models
{
    public class partial
    {

        public string Winner { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here my partial view

```
@model my_photos.Models.partial

<div class="body">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="header"> 
                    <h1 class="nav-heading">Data</h1> 
                        <p class="paragraph" > Winner :@Model.Winner.ToString()  </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="header">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

and here is my main layout in shared folder

```
@model my_photos.Models.partial
@{
    Layout = null; 
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>_Layout</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Style/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Style/Side_barnav.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h3> Photos app</h3>
            <p> In this app my major concerns are with the <strong>theaming</strong>!</p>
            <div class="nav">
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index", "Default")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About","About", "Default")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact","Contact", "Default")</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    <section>
            @RenderBody()
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_partial.cshtml")
    </section>
        <footer>
            <div class="fotter-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Default")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About","About","Default")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact","Contact","Default")</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Resources","Resources","Default")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Testimonial","Testimonial","Default")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Team","Team","Default")</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Default")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Default")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Default")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

when ever i try to get value form the model it give me the following error.
kindly help me through this.

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Comment: This is happening because your model that is passed to the partial is `null`, as you can see, in actions `About` and `Index` there is no model being passed.

Comment: so how could i resolve it. should i create model for both of them and why it is necessary

Comment: I updated my answer with some clarifications for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your model is `null`, as you can see, in actions `About` and `Index` there is no model being passed. Also [`partial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) is a keyword in C#, it will be better to have a more signifiant name.

To solve this you have to pass a model to every view that uses that layout that is expecting this model. In your case is `null` and an error is thrown.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Massage = "Hello Word";
    var model = new my_photos.Models.partial(){
           Winner = "Shafee Jan"
       };
    return View(model);
}
```

It is necesary to pass the model because on the below line of code the partial is rendered by **default** with the current view model.

```
@Html.Partial("_partial.cshtml", Model) @* Model is passed by default if there is no other parameter specified *@
```

---

I think what you really want to do is to call the `_RightView` action in your layout.

```
@Html.Action("_RightView", "Default")
```

Don't forget to modify the action to return a partial view and the passing of model in the other actions won't be necessary

```
public ActionResult  _RightView() {
    var model = new my_photos.Models.partial(){
        Winner = "Shafee Jan"
    };
    //ViewData["name"] = model;
    return PartialView("_partial", model);
}
```

Comment: i have created tow more models and have place them in the rite place.
when i comment model from the partial view application runs fine.
but if i uncomment  the model application return the following error.
[InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Views/Shared/Partial.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: @ShafeeJaan The call should be without `~/Views/Shared/`, the correct way to call is `@Html.Partial("_partial.cshtml")`. If the type of the model used by the layout and partial view are different, please pass the right type to 2nd parameter (instead of `Model`, from my example)

Comment: i have also pass Model in the argument as well but still its not working.

Comment: @ShafeeJaan Can you update your question with the new changes?

Comment: i have updated my all code in the following line.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350465/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-my-photos-models-profile

Answer (score 0):

hey this is not a big problem you are giving partial class reference to both layout and partial view.

so if you are access a _RightView Action it does't thrown a error because you are passing a object to view properly but when comes it partial view you are not passing object reference so just pass the model in

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_partial.cshtml",Model)

That's it